# Search Knockout Array for Duplicate Entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a KO array called self.Employees which has a list of user names which is displayed on the screen.  Users have the ability to enter new users to the system and I would like to throw an error if the name is already in the array.  I am able to throw an error if the textbox is blank, however I cannot seem to do the search properly.  Below is the code I have tried.

```
  var employeeList = [
    new Employee(1, "Jack Johnson"),
    new Employee(2, "Alice Smith"),
    new Employee(3, "Clark Kent"),
    new Employee(4, "Bruce Banner"),
    new Employee(5, "Alan Moore")
  ];
```

self.Employees = ko.observableArray(employeeList) //Requirement!

```
      var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Employees, function(item)
        {
          return item.employeeName == employee.Name;
        });

    if(match === employee.Name) {
        self.error("Duplicate entry.");
        return;
      }



      // Check if a field is blank before adding to array THIS WORKS
      if(employee.Name == "") {
        self.error("A new employee name is required.");
        return;
      }
      else {
        self.error("");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is that `match` is set to an employee object, and therefore cannot be compared like this:

```
// Wrong
if (match === employee.Name) { }
```

Instead, you could try:

```
// Right
if (match && match.Name === employee.Name) { }
```

---

If you want to do some more refactoring, I suggest implementing `newEmployeeValid` as a `pureComputed` property. Here's an example

```js
function Employee(id, name) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.id = id;
}

function App(employees) {
 
  this.employeeList = ko.observableArray(employees);
  this.newEmployeeName = ko.observable("");
  
  this.nameValid = ko.pureComputed(
    () => this.newEmployeeName().length > 1
  );
  
  this.nameUnique = ko.pureComputed(
    () => !this.employeeList().some(
            other => other.name() === this.newEmployeeName()
          )
  );
  
  this.error = ko.pureComputed(
    () => {
      if (!this.nameValid()) 
        return `Names should have more than 1 character`;
      if (!this.nameUnique()) 
        return `We already have an employee named ${this.newEmployeeName()}`
        
      return null;
    }
  )
  
  this.employeeValid = ko.pureComputed(
    () => !!this.error()
  );
  
  this.addEmployee = () => {
    this.employeeList.push(
      new Employee(null, this.newEmployeeName())
    )
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new App([
  new Employee(1, "Jack"),
  new Employee(2, "Alice"),
  new Employee(3, "Clark"),
  new Employee(4, "Bruce"),
  new Employee(5, "Alan")
]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: employeeList">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>

<input data-bind="textInput: newEmployeeName">
<button data-bind="click: addEmployee, enable: employeeValid">Add</button>
<p data-bind="text: error, visible: error" style="color: red"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the "some" function to check if it exists inside of the array of objects.
It might be much cleaner as well.

```
var name = "check if this name exists"

var itExists = arrayOfObjects.some(employee => employee.name === name);
```

this would become true if name was inside of the array of objects as any of the employee' names

Comment: I seem am still having a few challenges.  Maybe I am doing something wrong.  I will update my code with additional information in regards to the KO array